# JQuery - Display a hyperlinked text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Looking for some help on displaying a hyperlink from choices selected by a user. What I am attempting to do is form a sentence with links based on checkbox selections.

So it should be like this...

You have indicated an interest in **Writing Support**, **Parking**, and **Housing**. - those keywords should be links.

I've researched and pulled some code and got it to display the href but not sure how to dynamically create the link from the choices. Appreciate any help.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="resource" value="Housing" href="http://housing.fake.com"> Housing</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="resource" value="Parking" href="https://Parking.fake.com"> Parking</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="resource" value="Writing Support" href="https://writing.fake.com"> Writing Support</input>


<div id="result"></div>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Show Me the Resources">

var $result = $('#result');

$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    var total = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    if (total <= 0 ) {
        $('#result').text('You have not indicated any interest. Please choose some options.');
    }
    else if (total == 1) {
        $('#result').text('You have indicated an interest in ' + $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('href') + '. Please click on the link to learn more about these resources.');
    } else {
        $('#result').text('You have indicated an interest in ');
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {
            if(i == total-1) {          
                $result.append('and ' + $(this).attr('href') + '.<br/> Please click on the links to learn more about these resources.');
            } else {
                $result.append($(this).attr('href') + ', ');
            }
        });  
    }
});
```

[JFFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu8wrfhh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
$('#result').html('You have indicated an interest in ' + '<a href="' 
+ $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('href') + '">'
+ $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('href') + '</a> '
+ '. Please click on the link to learn more about these resources.');
```

Comment: I've been at this for a day and you solved it in a minute! I appreciate both answers. They ultimately solved my question. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you need help, don't hesitate ;)